# LoadError despite gem install and gemrat addition to gem file

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm on windows 7. I can't add/require gems. Trying to pull data into hashes from an excel spreadsheet. I get the same problem following a tutorial that uses data_mapper. In CMD, I'm in the folder in question.

```
gem install simple-spreadsheet
gemrat simple-spreadsheet
```

This shows the gem is installed in the gem-file. If I do:

```
gem list
```

it's in there. In Sublime Text, I start my code with:

```
require 'simple-spreadsheet'
```

but if I run the code from CMD, it comes back with:

```
cannot load such file: simple-spreadsheet
```

This may be due to using a different version, and may be fixable by RVM (thought this itself is apparently a pain to install on Windows?).

Comment: What happens if you put this in your command prompt: 1) require 'simple-spreadsheet'; 2) the code you want to call

Comment: Assume you mean CMD (irb)?

If so, that generates a TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved via adding the gem manually into the gem-file, using Notepad.